# Upper estimates for $\int_0^M |f(x)|^2 dx$ and $ \int_0^M f(x) dx$ when $\|f\|_{\infty}\le M$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Let $M>0$ be fixed and let $f$ be a continuous real valued function such that
$$\|f\|_{\infty}\le M,$$
where $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ denotes the sup-norm.

Under these assumption, I need an upper estimate for
$$\int_0^M |f(x)|^2 dx\quad\text{ and }\quad \int_0^M f(x) dx.$$

About me the correct ones are the following:
$$\int_0^M |f(x)|^2 dx\le M^3$$

and

$$\int_0^M f(x) dx\le M^2.$$

Could someone please tell me if am I right or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your estimates are right.

Comment: That is correct: $\int_0^M |f(x)|^2 dx\le \int_0^M M^2 dx =  M^3$ and similarly for the other one. What are your doubts about it?

Comment: It's pretty easy to verify that the upper bound is sharp. Just let $f(x)\equiv M$.

Comment: @MartinR about the first one. I apologize if it is a dumb question, but it is part of a more difficult exercise for my math class. I wanted to be sure about that, because starting from this I have to built the remaining part of the exercise.

Comment: @Fred thank you.

Comment: @MartinR thank you, too.